# How do I create a hidden menu with hidden articles?

Tags: articles, menu

The following is what I'm doing:

1. Created a Category
2. Created an Article and stored in the Category
3. Created a new Menu without linking to a module
4. Created a new Menu Item within the new menu; single Article option, and then selected the Article created in step 2.
   Got the link from this page which shows the URL and Article ID at the end.
5. Got the ID from the Menu Manager (added &Itemid=xxx to the end of the URL)

In step 4, I should have been able to retrieve the hidden Article with the word 'Article' visible at the top. When I first did it, I was able to retrieve that page. Now I am not able to retrieve it.

In step 5, I added &Itemid=xxx (using mmy item ID in place of xxx), to the end of the URL thinking it would now link directly to the Article and associate with the specific menu id number. That didn't work either.

Any suggestions? I'm trying to create and selectively show hidden 'thank you', and various other hidden pages as part of a specific process. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I was making the error by not using an absolute link. The above steps do work. I was simply copying and pasting the URL.